# How does the primary and secondary voltage of a transformer be in the opposite phase in the vector diagram?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, electromagnetism, electrical

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBQuRE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

According to the polarity marking, the input and the output voltage should be in the same phase. I've included a simulation result which also shows that the input and the output have no phase difference.

But while studying the phasor diagram I have found that all phasor diagrams showing that the primary and secondary voltages are in the opposite phase. [N.B. polarity marking is the same as the picture above].

[image]

Comment: (b) and (c) indicate they are in phase (the minus sign) so how did you conclude they are not and where did the picture come from?

Comment: Picture is from "A Textbook of Electrical Technology , Volume 2 by B.L. Theraja. What aboutV1 & V2 ? There is no negative sign.

Comment: The picture cannot be commented on without knowing precisely what circuit it applies to.

Comment: Transformer without magnetic leakage connected to a. Resistive load , b. Inductive load, c. Capacitive load

Comment: Are dots shown?

Comment: Voltage measured from polarity dot to non-polarity on one side of the single phase transformer, is directly in phase with the voltage measured from polarity dot to non-polarity on the other side.  This is well codified in IEEE transformer standards (C57).  Your author may be using some other convention.

Comment: 1. B L thareja's that book is not trustworthy (as I have heard from my professor).      2. Diagram (a) is not possible because primary and secondary are both linked with same flux so the there induced emfs must be in phase.

Comment: So your question is really about the un-trustworthiness of a book?

Comment: I was also thinking diagram 'a' is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The primary and secondary induced voltages (E1 and E2) are in phase as shown. However they are 180 deg out of phase with the primary applied terminal voltage (V1).

Using -E1 just makes it easier to draw the phasor diagram.

Comment: How does that explain diagram (a)?

Comment: Only possible explanation that I can come up with is that daigram (a) is wrong. Both the induced emfs must be in the same phase because they are linked with the same flux.

Comment: Then your answer is sitting on shaky ground.

Comment: Kindly clarify. Primary and secondary coils are linked with the same flux(that is why we use the iron core(to magnify the flux, and to link both the coils with it)).

Comment: Listen, I agree with you that with the dots as shown in the OP's first diagram then the output and input voltage phasors should be in phase but that's not the point here - the OP is showing some pictures that contradict this and contradict each other and that cannot be ignored - your answer ignores the contradiction and that therefore doesn't answer the OP's question. Sometimes you can't make a decent answer because of anomalies in the question. Sometimes you have to address  anomalies before making a plain answer. Neil's answer says it's trivial to change phase and that may be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Changing flux in a transformer core induces a voltage in all turns. It does not matter whether these turns are part of the primary, the secondary, or any other winding, all turns generate the same voltage in the same phase.

It's trivial to change the phase of any winding, its polarity, by reversing the connections to it, if that's convenient. It appears that in your diagrams, it might have been convenient to draw the voltages with opposite phases to avoid cluttering the diagram.

Many people freely flip polarities when it doesn't really matter, only getting rigorous when they need to, for instance when connecting two primary windings in the same phase.

Comment: I’ve seen a large power transformer delivered from a major manufacturer that was wound backwards at factory.  Solution was to swap leads as you describe (and modified the nameplate drawing so technicians wouldn’t be confused when they open the tank years later for maintenance).